# How to add points on the x/y grid with button

Tags: java

I'm new to Java Swing and I'm writting a program, into which user types few X's and Y's and then the program shows on x/y grid those points. I drew the grid with Graphics2D, but now the problem is with drawing those points. I'm adding every X and Y to separate ArrayList and then after clicking the button 'Draw' it should draw all of them, but I don't really know how. I've searched few topics and tutorials, but still can't get into it.

Here is the code of my DrawPoints class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class DrawPoints extends JPanel {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public DrawPoints(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillOval(x*20, y*20, 5, 5); //20 is the difference between every point on my grid
    }
}
```

And here is part of my actionListener function

```
if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Draw")) { //Button is called 'Draw'
                for (int i = 0; i < dataX.size(); i++) { //dataX is an arrayList with all X's
                    DrawPoints drawPoints = new DrawPoints(dataX.get(i), dataY.get(i)); //dataY is an arrayList with all Y's
                    points.add(drawPoints); //points is a JPanel added in the main frame
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm adding every X and Y to separate ArrayList and then after clicking the button 'Draw' it should draw all of them,

That approach is wrong.

All the data needed to paint the points should be part of the `DrawPoints` class:

1. The `ArrayList should be an instance variable of the class.
2. You would create a method like `addPoint(...)` in the `DrawPoints` class. This method would simply take the point and add it to the ArrayList and then invoke `repaint()` to make sure the point is painted on the panel.
3. The `paintComponent(…)` method would then be changed to iterate through all the pointes in the ArrayList and then paint each point.

   > I'm writting a program, into which user types few X's and Y's

So as the user type the x/y points you would invoke the `addPoint(…)` method of your `DrawPoints` class.
You will also need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your `DrawPaoints` class to give your panel a size so a layout manager can be used.
Check out the `Draw On Component` example found in [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a working example that uses this approach. The code presented there is more complicated then you will need because it allows the user to use the mouse to create the rectangles to be painted.

Comment: One other thing: @OP also needs to set or override Size/preferredSize to be big enough to show the points

Comment: So first of all, I should mention it before, my program after adding all those points is saving it into the file (that was obligatory in my exercise) and then button 'Draw' reads them and invoke addPoints(...), here is DrawPoints, but still doesn't work

`public void addPoints(int x, int y) { 
 this.dataX.add(x); 
 this.dataY.add(y); 
 repaint(); 
} 
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
 super.paintComponent(g); 
 for (int i = 0; i < dataX.size(); i++) { 
 g.fillOval((dataX.get(i) * 20), (dataY.get(i) * 20), 5, 5); } } `

I don't know why code formatting doesn't work

Comment: Code formatting does not work in comments. Update your question with your [mre] demonstrating the problem. Note we don't have access to your data file, so you would just invoke addPoints() manually with hardcoded values in the "MRE". Once you get the painting working then you worry about reading the information from a file.

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.